# How to get banking transactions from Quickbooks using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

How to get banking transactions from Quickbooks using PHP SDK?

[image]

I created code for OAuth. Then i create serviceContext object and DataService object. What should i do next?

Comment: We are not a tutorial / guide service, trial and error is a excellent way to learn

Comment: I read manuals / tutorials a few days before creating question. API documentation do not say anything about it.

Comment: This is not supported yet via the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the sensitivity of user's banking data, this is not supported by QBO v3 services API and it's only available in the QBO UI.